# Examples of Fano manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, kahler-manifolds

A manifold $M$ is called Fano if its first Chern class $c_1(X)$ is positive. Equivalently, the anti-canonical bundle $-K_M$ is positive.

I know that good examples are the projective space and more generally the Grassmannian manifold.

Other than these two, are there any other "standard" examples of Fano manifolds that are well-known?

Thank you! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of toric examples.

Comment: Low-degree hypersurfaces in projective space are Fano by the adjunction formula.

Comment: The Mukai--Umemura 3fold is one that has interested many people, especially since Tian's 1997 paper where he introduced K--stability